# How to merge a lot of bitmaps into one

Tags: java, android-bitmap

I have one hundred images of a drone flying above the field; I want to make one big bitmap out of them and display it in the imageview. I don't really know how to do it at all. If you want i can send the images but i think it is unneccessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
public Bitmap mergeMultipleImages(Bitmap[] img_bitmaps){

    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(img_bitmaps[0].getWidth() * 2, img_bitmaps[0].getHeight() * 2, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    for (int i = 0; i < img_bitmaps.length; i++) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(img_bitmaps[i], img_bitmaps[i].getWidth() * (i % 2), img_bitmaps[i].getHeight() * (i / 2), paint);
    }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: hi. i've just fixed the rest part of my code and discovered that result is null